# How to perform a search action by android custom keyboard action button?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I'm developing an android custom keyboard. I need to perform search action, move cursor to next text field action according to the text fields that user selected. How to perform those actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I got the answer.**

```
getCurrentInputConnection().performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
getCurrentInputConnection().performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
getCurrentInputConnection().performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```